# Validation is not working on Registration & Login form

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I've following this [Blog](http://imrealashu.in/code/laravel/multi-auth-with-laravel-5-2-2/) for multi table authentication. I downloaded the project as it is and run the project. Everything works but validation is not working. Now message showing while I post an empty form.
Here is the code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
    {{  csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Register
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

According to the code error should be shown. I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: Did you add validation to the `Request` or `Controller`? If not check out laravel documentation, there are a lot of examples https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Comment: Add your controller code.

Comment: yes validation rules are there,its will be more clear to you,it you visite the blog i provided

Comment: no it won't. post your controller codes or ask the guy who gave you an answer below.

Answer (score -1):

There is no validation rules or incorrect validation rules in your post controller.

Comment: Stuff like *"I think"* are comments, to which you have enough rep to do so under the question.